# Replace all \" with \\" in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace all `\"` in my string with `\\"` (`\"` in `<div style=\"font-size:0.9em\">`)

```
var str = '{"CarID":"Z100","alerts":[{"AlertType":"Head <b>southeast</b> on <b>Tân Hải</b> toward <b>Trường Chinh</b><div style=\"font-size:0.9em\">Pass by nhan cuoi dep (on the right)</div>"}],"customizedLocations":[]}';

str = str.replace(/\"/g, '\\\\"');
```

I want the output is (`\"` in `style` is replaced by `\\"`):

`{"VehicleID":"Z100","alerts":[{"AlertType":"Head <b>southeast</b> on <b>Tân Hải</b> toward <b>Trường Chinh</b><div style=\\"font-size:0.9em\\">Pass by nhan cuoi dep (on the right)</div>"}],"customizedLocations":[]}`

But actually I get is (ALL `"` is replaced by `\\"`):

`{\\"VehicleID\\":\\"Z100\\",\\"alerts\\":[{\\"AlertType\\":\\"Head <b>southeast</b> on <b>Tân Hải</b> toward <b>Trường Chinh</b><div style=\\"font-size:0.9em\\">Pass by nhan cuoi dep (on the right)</div>\\"}]}`

I don't want to use jQuery, can somebody help me!

Comment: Why do you want that? Applying string manipulation functions to a JSON serialized string looks like a horrible idea.

Comment: if i don't replace `\"` with `\\"`, i can't parse that string to object (use JSON.parse)

Comment: Well, it's a valid JSON, but you cannot just take any arbitrary string, wrap it with single quotes and expect its semantics to be kept. You need to explain the underlying problem: how did you get this code? Where and how does this string come from?

Comment: I get this string from Google Maps, when I use GSON to parse it to my defined object, it's ok. But when I pass that string as a parameter to javascript function in Android webview, I can't use JSON.parse in this function to convert it to object

Comment: Well, if you retrieve that string from an API and use it as-is - it will work. But what you've done is copy-pasted it, which you just cannot do that easily. You still have to explain the whole flow, it's not obvious how you get that in your code.

Comment: webView.loadUrl("javascript:getAlertsOnMap('" + JsonStr +"');");

Comment: so what is `JsonStr`? PS: I don't believe it's 40 minutes passed and there is still no the proper explanation on what you're actually doing :-S (pps: it must be in a question not in comments)

Comment: I don't want to overbloat the comment area, but it would be very reasonable to use the tag `regex` for the question and maybe remove the tag `html`. People looking explicitly for regular expressions will find your question easier and faster.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, this is whole flow: I have a json file in sdcard, Android app read it and use GSON to parse to object. After that, I update my object (ex: remove some alerts). And convert this object to json again, pass this json to javascript in webview, in here, I use JSON.parse to get a new object, I will use this new object to draw a new route on Map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a little problem in your regex. The backslash `\` means escape. So when you write `\"` it finds only one quotation mark, the backslash escapes it as it is a special character.
You have to escape both the backslash and the quotation mark:

```
str = str.replace(/\\\"/g, '\\\\"');
```

This will produce the wished result.

Please read the comment from the user zerkms below your question. I don't really understand what this replacing is good for. Maybe you have the so called x-y problem:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

EDIT:

The above posted code line want work, because of the reasons explained in the comment below from the user zerkms. There is a workaround using raw string:

```
String.raw`\"`.replace(/\"/g, '\\"');
```

This is tested and should work.

Comment: `'\"'.replace(/\\\"/g, '\\\\"');` Your suggestion does nothing since there is nothing to replace (since there is, as you mentioned, no slashes in the real string at all).

Comment: Thanks @zerkms! I posted to fast without prior testing.

Comment: Thanks @cezar, it worked, but i edited a little `String.raw`\"`.replace(/\\"/g, '\\"');`

Comment: Because of the back quotes the code in your comment is cut up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fetching a path from HTML input tag and you need to replace the \ in path with \\ for further processing in code. You can use the following

```
var myString = $('#myID').val(); // c:\User\path
console.log(myString.split('\\').join('\\\\')); // c:\\User\\path
```